# Sockets: Passing unsigned char array from C to JAVA

Tags: java, c++, c, sockets, unsigned-char

C side:

```
unsigned char myBuffer[62];
fread(myBuffer,sizeof(char),62,myFile);
send(mySocket, myBuffer, 62,0);
```

JAVA side:

```
bufferedReader.read(tempBuffer,0,62);
```

Now in JAVA program i receive (using socket)  values less than `0x80` in C program with no problems, but i receive `0xFD` value for all values equal or greater than `0x80` in C program.
I need perfect solution for this problem.

Comment: Java is more explicit than C about character encoding. You must know the character encoding that your C program uses, so your Java program interprets the bytes using the same encoding.

Comment: @Raedwald if this is text at all and not binary data; OP doesn't tell

Comment: OK, so what about you told us exactly what you want to do? This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) to me

Comment: I want to passing byte stream from C program to JAVA program, InputStream solve my problem. Thank you! @fge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `Reader` to read bytes, use an `InputStream`!

A `Reader` is meant to read *characters*; it receives a stream of bytes and (tries and) converts these bytes to characters; you lose the original bytes.

In more details, a `Reader` will use a [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html); this decoder is configured so that unknown byte sequences are [replaced](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html#REPLACE); and the encoding used here likely replaces unknown byte sequences with character 0x00fd, hence your result.

Also, you don't care about signed vs unsigned; `1000 0000` may be 128 as an `unsigned char` in C and -127 as a `byte` in Java, it still remains `1000 0000`.

---

If what you send is really text, then it means the charset you have chosen for decoding is not the good one; you must know the encoding in which the files on your original system are written.